# Test all pixels by changing color on screen touch

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas, android-bitmap, pixel

I'm developing a code in which I have to test if all pixels are working fine by changing the color of every pixel. Currently, I'm able to successfully change the color by painting the screen on touch event when the user touches the screen, but I'm not able to keep track of pixels being painted.

The problem is on **onTouchEvent** if we use **event.getX() and event.getY()** it doesn't give the values of all pixels touched by the finger.

**My requirement is to check all pixels by changing the color and once the whole screen is painted pass or fail the test depending upon whether all pixels were colored by the user.**

Comment: What?! You mean the user has to press to every single pixels of the screen to test them? How is he supposed to do that? The latest smartphones have huge definition in order to NOT see the matrix of pixels when you look at the screen. So how are you supposed to select them individually? And even so, it would take forever!

Comment: No, you got it wrong, I meant to say that when the user touches the screen I want to detect how many pixels were affected by the touch. As the finger has larger surface area than pixels definitely not just one pixel.would be affected. So, how to get all touched pixels is my question?

Comment: So I suggest to update your question as it's not clear at all. Otherwise, I don't know if it's possible but there is probably a method of the [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) which is closed to what you're looking for, like `getSize()`